# Cannot centralise social buttons

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, social-networking

I'm developing a page that outputs an image and then in turns allows a user to share/tweet/... their image. All works fine except for one thing, the `Sharrre` buttons won't centralise in the page.

I've tried all-sorts, from the usual wrapping the divs in a parent div that has style rules of `width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;` all the way to `text-align: center` in a last ditched attempt of hope but all to no avail. Seeing as I'm using jQuery Mobile, I've even gone down the route of utilising a grid in an attempt, but still those pesky buttons glue to the left of the page as if a cliff sits in between there and the center. **Has anyone any idea!?** I've created a JSBin to demonstrate the problem (JSFiddle is down) - http://jsbin.com/qeqowofu/1/edit

Sharrre Github: https://github.com/Julienh/Sharrre/blob/master/jquery.sharrre.js [includes .js files]

Many thanks in advance!

--

HTML:

```
<body>  
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
             <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="output">
            <p>Welcome Message</p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
            <div id="photo">                        
                <?php               
                    if (isset($_GET['key'])) {  
                        try {           
                            $photo = $share->getPhoto((int)$_GET['key']);
                            echo '
                                 <div class="ui-grid-a my-breakpoint"><div class="ui-block-a"><img src="images/'.$photo.'" style="width: 768px; height: 432px;"/>
                                 <br><br>
                                 <div id="twitter" data-url="http://url.co.uk" data-text="Popup text" data-title="Tweet"></div>
                                 <div id="facebook" data-url="http://url.co.uk" data-text="Popup text" data-title="Share"></div>
                                 <div id="googleplus" data-url="http://url.co.uk" data-text="Popup text" data-title="+1"></div>
                                 </div></div>
                            ';
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            echo "<div class='ui-grid-a my-breakpoint'><div class='ui-block-a'><p style='color: #c53131'>".$e->getMessage()."</p></div></div>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='ui-grid-a my-breakpoint'><div class='ui-block-a'><p style='color: #c53131'>The URL you gave us has no key. Please make sure it reads ...photo.php?key=123456 and we'll look again!</p></div></div>";
                    }
                ?>
```

CSS:

```
        @media all and (max-width: 35em) {
            .my-breakpoint .ui-block-a,
            .my-breakpoint .ui-block-b,
            .my-breakpoint .ui-block-c,
            .my-breakpoint .ui-block-d,
            .my-breakpoint .ui-block-e {
              width: 90%;
              float:none;
            }
        }

        @media all and (min-width: 45em) {
            .my-breakpoint.ui-grid-b .ui-block-a { width: 90%;}
        }

        #photo {margin-top: 40px;}
        #photo a {text-decoration: none;}
        #photo a:hover {color: #fff;}

        .ui-block-a {
            text-align: center !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        #output {background-color: #f6f6f6; height: 100px; margin-top: -16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;}
        #output p {text-shadow: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; padding: 40px;}

          .sharrre{
            margin:55px 0 0 50px;
            float:left;             
          }
          .sharrre .box a:hover{
            text-decoration:none;
          }
          .sharrre .count {
            color:#525b67;
            display:block;
            font-size:18px;
            font-weight:bold;
            line-height:40px;
            height:40px;
            position:relative;
            text-align:center;
            width:70px;
            -webkit-border-radius:4px;
            -moz-border-radius:4px;
            border-radius:4px;
            border:1px solid #b2c6cc;
            background: #fbfbfb; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%, #f6f6f6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fbfbfb), color-stop(100%,#f6f6f6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb 0%,#f6f6f6 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fbfbfb', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
          }
          .sharrre .count:before, .sharrre .count:after {
            content:'';
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            left:49%;
            width:0;
            height:0;
          }
          .sharrre .count:before {
            border:solid 7px transparent;
            border-top-color:#b2c6cc;
            margin-left:-7px;
            bottom: -14px;
          }
          .sharrre .count:after {
            border:solid 6px transparent;
            margin-left:-6px;
            bottom:-12px;
            border-top-color:#fbfbfb;
          }
          .sharrre .share {
            color:#FFFFFF;
            display:block;
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
            height:30px;
            line-height:30px;
            margin-top:8px;
            padding:0;
            text-align:center;
            text-decoration:none;
            width:70px;
            -webkit-border-radius:4px;
            -moz-border-radius:4px;
            border-radius:4px; 
          }
          #twitter .share {
            text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #0077be;
            filter: dropshadow(color=#0077be, offx=1, offy=0); 
            border:1px solid #0075c5;
            background: #26c3eb;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26c3eb 0%, #26b3e6 50%, #00a2e1 51%, #0080d6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#26c3eb), color-stop(50%,#26b3e6), color-stop(51%,#00a2e1), color-stop(100%,#0080d6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26c3eb 0%,#26b3e6 50%,#00a2e1 51%,#0080d6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26c3eb 0%,#26b3e6 50%,#00a2e1 51%,#0080d6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26c3eb 0%,#26b3e6 50%,#00a2e1 51%,#0080d6 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(top, #26c3eb 0%,#26b3e6 50%,#00a2e1 51%,#0080d6 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#26c3eb', endColorstr='#0080d6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #DDDDDD, 0 1px 0 #5cd3f1 inset;
          }
          #facebook .share {
            text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #26427e;
            filter: dropshadow(color=#26427e, offx=1, offy=0); 
            border:1px solid #24417c;
            background: #5582c9; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5582c9 0%, #33539a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5582c9), color-stop(100%,#33539a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5582c9 0%,#33539a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5582c9 0%,#33539a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5582c9 0%,#33539a 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(top, #5582c9 0%,#33539a 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5582c9', endColorstr='#33539a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #DDDDDD, 0 1px 0 #80a1d6 inset;
          }
          #googleplus .share {
            text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #222222;
            filter: dropshadow(color=#222222, offx=1, offy=0); 
            border:1px solid #262626;
            background: #6d6d6d; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%, #434343 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6d6d6d), color-stop(100%,#434343)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%,#434343 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%,#434343 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%,#434343 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(top, #6d6d6d 0%,#434343 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6d6d6d', endColorstr='#434343',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #DDDDDD, 0 1px 0 #929292 inset;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a div to contain both social icons, with this style:

```
.shareContainer{
      width:240px;
      margin:0 auto;
      text-align:center;
}
```

And also update your ".sharrre" class like this:

```
.sharrre{
    margin:55px 0 0 50px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

Here is updated [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/pigoyite/1/edit)

Hope this helps as a start point.